# Google Cloud Payment Method API

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Is there any API for Google Cloud - that allows you to create billing payment method to be created?

I can create a billing account for Google Cloud using an API https://cloud.google.com/billing/reference/rest/v1/billingAccounts, however I can't seem to find a way to add payment method to this billing account.

Did any one ran in this problem before?

Answer (score 2):

Google Cloud Billing API is designed to help you manage billing accounts, and their linkage to projects. Google Cloud does not provide an API to add payment information, such as credit card numbers.

Google Cloud's Billing API is designed to comply with PCI Data Security Standards (DSS). [According to PCI DSS](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/PCI%20SSC%20Quick%20Reference%20Guide.pdf),

> The PCI DSS applies to all entities that store, process, and/or transmit cardholder data.

That means you. If you write an application that stores cardholder data and transmits it programmatically, then you, yourself, may require a PCI DSS assessment of your CDE (cardholder data environment). This is likely not what you intend.

The [Stripe API for Payment Methods](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/create#create_payment_method-card) offers similar guidance:

> When creating with a card number, **you must meet the requirements for PCI compliance**. We strongly recommend using Stripe.js instead of interacting with this API directly.